# How to properly append text to TextView from SharedPreferences file instead of overwriting it?

Tags: java, android, save, append, sharedpreferences

I have two classes, one class is saving weight, then in the other class/ activity I want a log that appends the weight along with the date and time, then makes a new line and displays the next weight. This way the user can keep track of their daily weight changes.

Problem is I'm brand new to Java and clearly am getting stuck on a silly problem. Each time I try append it instead just overwrites. I probably need to save it and then add it? maybe? I've tried a few different things and nothing is working all that well.

This is day 3 of Java. Apologies.

Tried making a list that is saved with sharedpreferences. Either did it wrong or it didnt work. Also tried just calling for the weight and appending it, but it overwrites it all.

My Logging activity:

```
public class LogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView logger;
    //TextView more;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        Button back = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

        logger = findViewById(R.id.txtLog);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();


        SharedPreferences log = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", 0);

        //Float value = log.getFloat("floatingLog",0);
        Float value = log.getFloat("weight", 0);
        //more.append(logger + "Weight: " + value.toString() + " at: " + dateFormat.format(date) + "\n");
        logger.append("Weight: " + value.toString() + " at: " + dateFormat.format(date) + "\n");

        // Adding back button
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

//        SharedPreferences settings7 = getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
//        String wordsString = settings7.getString("words","");
//        String[] itemWords = wordsString.split(",");
//        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
//        for (int i = 0; i < itemWords.length; i++){
//            items.add(itemWords[i]);
//        }
//        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
//            Log.d("list", items.get(i));
//        }




    }
}
```

This is getting the sharedpreferences from here, in my ProfileActivity:

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWeight)).setText(findViewById(R.id.txtNewWeight).toString());
                floatingLog = weight.toString();
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                floatingWeight = Float.valueOf(newWeight.getText().toString());

                editor.putString("floatingLog", floatingLog);
                editor.putFloat("weight", floatingWeight);
                editor.apply();
                editor.commit();
                weight.setText(String.valueOf(floatingWeight));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO!

actually in TextView, you can access to current value via `TextView#getText()` and after that you can update the text value similarly using `TextView#setText(String text)`

so you need to write something like this:

```
String currentText = logger.getText();
String updatedText = currentText + "Weight: " + value.toString() + " at: " + dateFormat.format(date) + "\n";
logger.setText(updatedText)
```

tada !

**UPDATE**

I think your problem is with how you save your records in your `sharedPrefs`
in this line
`editor.putFloat("weight", floatingWeight);` in this part you are overwriting the existing value,
simplest approach that comes to my mind is that instead of saving weight like this, you create an array of weights and append to end of it every day and store the array.
how ever it will be far more better if you use data base for this which gives you far more flexibility.

to use database take a look at Android official orm [Android Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) it is very simple and straightforward

Comment: Thanks! Like most, I've been lurking.. for years..

Gave the code a try. Maybe I'm not implementing it correctly or something, but its still just entirely replacing the current text instead of appending anything..

Did I mention that I have a main page that displays weight as well? Could that be why things are breaking? Although all the main page does is takes the weight value and writes it into a textbox to display current weight.. I'm totally lost sorry :P

Comment: what I understand from your comment is maybe when this code runs, your logger is not showing anything! and yes I just looked at your code again you are calling this in `onCreate`!
I will update my answer